# Counting homomorphisms of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> How many homomorphisms are there from $A_{5} × S_{3} × A_{4}$ to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

I know that $Z/2Z$ is generated by ome element and of order two. I know the respective order of the rest of these groups.

How do I put use these facts?

Comment: Hint: Any (non-trivial) such homomorphism will correspond to a normal subgroup of index $2$. Can you find such subgroups?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft why is this true? And I don't believe there is?

Comment: There certainly are such subgroups. And this is true by the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I still don't get it :( I feel dumb

Comment: Am I allowed to say that because $A_{5}/[A_{5},A_{5}]={1}$ the whole $A_5$ part maps to the trivial element?

Answer (score 1):

Every group homomorphism $A_5 \times S_3 \times A_4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ factors uniquely through the abelization
$$
    \operatorname{Ab}(A_5 \times S_3 \times A_4)
  \cong \operatorname{Ab}(A_5) \times \operatorname{Ab}(S_3) \times \operatorname{Ab}(A_4)
  \cong 1 \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3
  \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3.
$$
There exists precisely two group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$, namely the identity and the zero map.
There exists only one group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/3 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$, namely the zero map.
Because $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3$ is a coproduct we find that there exist two group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$, and thus precisely two group homomorphisms $A_5 \times S_3 \times A_4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$.